# PL/SQL plugin not working in SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube6.3, sonarqube-plugin

I want to use SonarQube for PL/SQL. I downloaded the plugin from the SonarQube Site and placed it into `$SONARQUBE_HOME/extensions/plugins`. Then I restarted the SonarQube Server but it didn't start up. When I removed the plugin it was working.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

The PL/SQL language is supported as part of the [SonarSource Developer Edition](https://www.sonarsource.com/plans-and-pricing/developer/), which is a commercial package for which you need a license.

This is why if you install it manually, this will not work.